# Change default url php

Tags: php, httpd.conf

How to change the default url. eg www.example.com/index.php  -> www.example.com

now i want to set it to www.example.com/test.php. Should i make changes in php.ini?

Comment: That is taken care of in your web server not in PHP.  Are you using Apache or something else?

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a link I guess.

Comment: yes i am using apache.Is there a config file for it?

Comment: yes, it's usually named `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using apache, you can do this through the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

[Check out the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).

Answer (score 2):

```
DirectoryIndex test.php
```

In your .htaccess or httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

You could set the htaccess `DirectoryIndex` to include test.php:

```
DirectoryIndex test.php index.php index.html
```

You could also setup a redirect from index.php:

```
header('Location: test.php'); //Must be before any content is sent out
```

Redirects will work from htaccess too:

```
Redirect 301 index.php test.php
```

The simplest thing to do, however, would be renaming the test.php file to index.php. Why not just do that? :P

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change this in Apache's configuration using the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive.

e.g. (In the correct `VirtualHost` section):

```
DirectoryIndex test.php
```

Although I can't see why on earth one would want to do that...